MAUI - How to detect double tap on a pin on Google Maps?
I would like to detect a double tap event on a pin on Google Maps. I currently detect a single tap like this:
foreach (var pin in map.Pins)
{
    pin.MarkerClicked -= MapListPage_MarkerClicked;
    pin.MarkerClicked += MapListPage_MarkerClicked;

}

I have tried looking at the docs, but couldn't find anything. Is there any way of detecting double tap events on Google Map pins?

Did you try the NumberOfTapsRequired proerty of the TapGestureRecognizer?

@LiyunZhang-MSFT Maps.Pin does not support TapGestureRecognizer

I would set up event handling for taps and implement a logic to differentiate double taps from single taps.
I'm sure the following could be improved, but take a look at this example:
private DateTime _lastTapTime = DateTime.MinValue;
private const int DoubleTapThreshold = 300; // Adjust as needed

private void OnPinClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var currentTapTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
    var timeDifference = currentTapTime - _lastTapTime;

    if (timeDifference.TotalMilliseconds <= DoubleTapThreshold)
    {
        // A double tap has been detected - do something with it
        OnPinDoubleTapped(sender as Pin);
    }

    _lastTapTime = currentTapTime;
}
private void OnPinDoubleTapped(Pin pin)
{
    // Your double-tap logic here
}


The Pin.MarkerClicked does not fire when it's double tapped. It only fires for single taps, or if there is a large delay between 2 taps. I cannot find a simple way to override this behavior

Ah... Take a look at this then, it might be what you are looking for: https://www.trycatchdebug.net/news/1317483/double-tap-detection-in-google-maps
